# Losing DataContext when using Datagrid in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Consider this XAML:

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NestedObject.Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding NestedObject.Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

In the case of the `TextBlock` the object property would be correctly displayed, but when using it in a `DataGrid`, nothing is displayed.

This is odd since I call it the same way in both cases and I thought that when no data context was specified it was falling back to the parent data context.

Am I missing something in the declaration ?

**Note**

I'm using the `UserControl` in the MainWindow and an object with a NestedObject property is assigned to its data context. Also, `Name` is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: If there is an instance of SomeObject in the UserControl's DataContext, `Binding SomeObject.Name` would not work, except SomeObject had itself a SomeObject property.

Comment: @Clemens You're right my bad, I'll edit to clarify that's not what I wanted to say.

Comment: @Clemens Here changed the naming, hope it clarifies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally bind a column in a `DataGrid` to a property of an item in the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource`, i.e. your current binding will only work if the `ItemsSource` property is bound or set to an `IEnumerable<T>` and the type `T` has a `SomeObject` property.

If you want to to bind to a property of another object, you could use a `{RelativeSource}` to explictly specify the source of the binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SomeObject.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.SomeObject.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding SomeObject.Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I tried to create another property in my `NestedObject` (see edit) which is a `List<string>` which woud contains the `Name` value. Calling it like so, `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding NestedObject.NameCollection}" />` doesn't work.

Comment: A list has no Name property. Does the TextBlock binding work? Then the column binding will never work because of what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: The Textblock binding does work. But not the one in the Datagrid, and yes I think I get it. I would have to implement an IEnumerable for that specific property.

Comment: @scharette - Check this article --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102927/wpf-xaml-binding-work-with-real-datacontext/34104653#34104653